# Question on digital sum of the square of $n$

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

If we set $f(n)=$ the digital sum of $n$，for example, $f(2024)= 2+0+2+4= 8$.

Are there any $n>375501$ in solutions to the equation $f(n^2)=9,$ except $n=10k$, $n=10^a+10^b+1$, $n=5 \cdot 10^a+1$ or $n=10^a+5$?
($k,a,b$ are integers, $k>0$, $a \ge b \ge 0$)

or can it be proved that there are only limited nontrivial $n$ such $f(n^2)=9$ ?

And when $f(n^2)=m$, $m=4,7,10,11,\ldots$  whether such $n$ is still limited or not ?

(if $f(n^2)\equiv m \pmod 9$, then $n^2 \equiv m \pmod 9$, only when $m \equiv 0,1,4,7 \pmod 9$ there are integer solutions $n$)

trivial solution :
if $f(n^2)=m$, then $f((10 n)^2)=m$，else if $n=A \times 10^k+B$ and $B^2<10^k$, $2AB<10^k$, $f(n)=m$, let $N= A \times 10^{k+1}+B$ then $f(N^2)=f(n^2)=m$

so these solutions like $10 n$ or $N$ are trivial to some degree.

Comment: Your question is hard to read. Is it possible to format it in Latex? And why do you work with integers as string. To me it seems better to use $n = \sum_{k=0}^m a_k \cdot 10^k$.

Comment: I 'm sorry. The question is published with mobile phone, and I'm too careless to think about how it will be when reading this question. Thanks for editing, and I'm sorry.

Comment: And there's mistake in the last two paragraph about trivial solution, it should be the digital sum of  square of n , instead of n, equals m. I'm really careless.

Comment: Just to clarify — you're asking about squares with digital sum 9?

Comment: Maybe you can find some useful hints in this short preprint of mine about a related topic: https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.10163
Good luck!

Comment: If $n=2 \cdot 10^a+1$ then $n^2=4 \cdot 10^{2a}+4 \cdot 10^a+1$ so $f(n^2)=9$.

Comment: Thanks for reply from Command Master, Marco and Adam, I want to find squares greater than 141001001001 (the square of 375501) which has digital sum 9, except some trivial solution. And maybe the solution of Adam can be included in the second form listed in the second paragraph when a equals b